# how to style span with value

Tags: html, css

I want to style span with value, I want text"yellow" set to color as yellow; and "red" color as red; here's example code:

```html
<ul class="color">
    <li class="all-color"> <span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-1">yellow</span>

    </li>
    <li class="all-color"> <span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-2">red</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you use html data attribute?

Comment: Anything particular? I have no clue what you want, but I can help you with a basic styling ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
span[data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-1"] {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

Similarly you can select another span.
As per question you wants to select the span by values.

Comment: display property must be set to apply vertical padding or margin to span.Just told if you needed it later

Comment: this is exactly what i need, all done with css only, it works! thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I know that jQuery has *not* been mentioned in this question, but this is what you could have done in case you used it:

```
$(".all-color").each(function () {
    $(this).css("color", $(this).text());
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r3wzLt36/)

The code changes the text color based on the color name you put there :)

Comment: Nice one, but what about non-defined colors by browser? Seems like it has some limitation with colors.

Comment: @AdamAzad I do agree with you, indeed it does has limitations. But as per question, it should be based on the color-name you put it. This is the simplest I came up with :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you have to make two classes as `red` & `yellow` and then assign those classes on `span` fields. In CSS, you have to set `color` property for field.

Check the code here:

```css
.red{
 color:red 
  }

.yellow{
 color:yellow 
  }
```

```html
<ul class="color">
    <li class="all-color"> <span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-1" class="yellow">yellow</span>

    </li>
    <li class="all-color"> <span data-vc-grid-filter-value=".vc_grid-term-2" class="red">red</span>

    </li>
</ul>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: Please, read the question again.

Comment: I read question. You want text yellow in yellow font color & red in red font color?